# Divide event duration into one-hour time slots (24-hour format)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table structured as follows

| lane | date | time | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020/01/01 | 10:30:00 | ON |
| A | 2020/01/01 | 11:10:00 | OFF |
| B | 2020/05/09 | 23:05:00 | ON |
| B | 2020/05/10 | 01:00:00 | OFF |

where:

- lane: lane where the event is recorded ON or OFF
- date: date format in which the event occurred
- time: time format in which the event occurred
- event: string 'ON' or 'OFF

The goal is to calculate for each time slot (0->23) how many minutes (as decimal) a lane remained open. 
-- time_slot = 0 => from 00:00:00 to 00:59:59

The output table should be in the form

| lane | date | time_slot | working_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020/01/01 | 10 | 30 |
| A | 2020/01/01 | 11 | 10 |
| B | 2020/05/09 | 23 | 55 |
| B | 2020/05/10 | 0 | 60 |

The problem is that StartTime and FinishTime can be on two different days (not necessarily consecutive) and therefore working_time is not always in 60-minute slots.

How can I fix this to get the correct result? valid for both sql and python

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Why `B, 2020/05/09, 23:05:00, ON` gives `B, 2020/05/09, 23, 55` as output?

Comment: @lemon because in the 23rd hour of that day there were only 55 minutes of "on" duration

Comment: this is quite complicated in SQL, if the time between ON and OFF events spans multiple hours then you will have to generate rows that aren't there in the input.  you will need another table with one row per time slot that you can join with in order to create the proper number of rows in the output

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in python is to use a generator that creates the slots on the fly:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


on_time = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0)
off_time = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 13, 10, 0)


def hour_floor(dt):
    return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour)


def hour_ceiling(dt):
    return hour_floor(dt + timedelta(hours=1))


def slots_between(start, end):
    slot_start = start
    slot_end = min(hour_ceiling(slot_start), end)
    duration = slot_end - slot_start
    yield slot_start, slot_end, duration
    while slot_end < end:
        slot_start = slot_end
        slot_end = min(slot_end + timedelta(hours=1), end)
        duration = slot_end - slot_start
        yield slot_start, slot_end, duration


for slot_start, slot_end, duration in slots_between(on_time, off_time):
    print(f'Slot {slot_start.hour} on {slot_start.date()} was {duration.seconds//60} minutes.')
```

Outputs:

```
Slot 10 on 2020-01-01 was 30 minutes.
Slot 11 on 2020-01-01 was 60 minutes.
Slot 12 on 2020-01-01 was 60 minutes.
Slot 13 on 2020-01-01 was 10 minutes.
```